# Convert certain numbers in a sentence such as date, time, phone number from numbers to words in Python

Tags: python, date, search, time, match

I am kind of new to Python so I apologize for my lacks. I have a code in python perfected with other users' help (thank you) that converts a date from numbers into words using dictionaries for days,months,years, like 3.6.2015 => march.third.two thousand fifteen using:
date = raw_input("Give date: ")
I want to input a sentence such as: "today is 3.6.2015, it is 10:00 o'clock and it's rainy" and from it I do not know how to search through the sentence for the date, or time, or phone number and to that date and time to apply the conversion.
If someone can please help, thank you.

Comment: The code is:            
sentence=raw_input("give: ")
mat=re.search('(\d{1,2})[/.-](\d{1,2})[/.-](\d+)$', sentence)           
my_date = mat.group(0)    list = re.split(r'[./-]', my_date)
  day = list[0]
month = list[1]
 year = list[2]   if dict_day.get(int(day)) != None:
day_print = dict_day.get(int(day)) and the same for month and year then: if list == re.split(r'[.]', my_date): #split by ./-
print "date:" ,  day_print, ".", month_print, ".", year_print BUT I want when i type: today is 3.6.2015 and it is sunny   to be displayed: today is march.third.two thousand fifteen and it is sunny

Answer (score 0):

You could use regular expressions:

```
import re

s = "today is 3.6.2015, it is 10:00 o'clock and it's rainy"

mat = re.search(r'(\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{4})', s)
date = mat.group(1)

print date  # 3.6.2015
```

Note, if there's nothing matching this regular expression in the input text, an `AttributeError` will be raised, that you'll either have to prevent (e.g. `if mat:`) or handle.

**EDIT**

Assuming you can turn your conversion code into a function, you could use `re.sub`:

```
import re

def your_function(num_string):
    # Whatever your function does
    words_string = "march.third.two thousand fifteen"
    return words_string

s = "today is 3.6.2015, it is 10:00 o'clock and it's rainy"

date = re.sub(r'(\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{4})', your_function, s)

print date 
# today is march.third.two thousand fifteen, it is 10:00 o'clock and it's rainy
```

Just modify `your_function` to change the `3.6.2015` into `march.third.two thousand fifteen`.

Comment: I understand but what I'm looking for is: sentence = raw_input("give it: ") and from it like "today is 3.6.2015", the date part to be shown as "today is march.third.two thousand fifteen".

Comment: how exactly to extract the date part and pass it through my conversion from numbers into words

Comment: how do I separate the date part from the rest of the sentence and then in the output today is march.third.two thousand fifteen

Comment: Updated my post with a different approach that may help.